# knockoutMVC with datepicker

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, knockout-2.0

I am using [Knockout MVC](http://knockoutmvc.com/) in my project and have problems adding datePicker.

Here's my code:
**Razor Code:**

```
@Html.Label("Date of birth: ")
@ko.Html.TextBox(m => m.DateofBirth, new{@class="date"})
```

**Javascript Code**

```
$('.date').datepicker({ dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy" });
```

Don't have any variants, what to do.

Answer (score 0):

try using this js

```
$('.date').val($.datepicker.formatDate('dd/mm/yy', new Date(year, month, 1)));
```

or for your specific problem try

```
$('.date').live('mousedown', function () { $('.date').datepicker({ dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy" }); });
```

Comment: Ok, datepiker is apeares but if I knockout update the model- my script don't update new elements with datepicker. (( I don't know how to intercept cknockout update events.

Comment: For last problem solving I used this: $('.date').live('mousedown', function () { $('.date').datepicker({ dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy" }); }); Now it automatically bind date-picker to new elements.

Answer (score 0):

I have made a KO binding for the datepicker please see my Github repo

https://github.com/AndersMalmgren/Knockout.Bindings

and demo: http://jsfiddle.net/H8xWY/2/